# tapped Ethernet frames are seen partially when interface MTU is smaller than tapped frames

Tags: tap

I have a following very simple topology where router **r1** sends ICMP "echo request" messages to **r2** with 2000 byte payloads and router **r2** replies to those messages with ICMP "echo reply" messages:

[image: passive network tap setup]

Routers Gi0/0/0 interfaces are with 9000 byte MTU. As seen on the drawing, there is also a passive network tap between those two routers which mirrors traffic to bond0 interface in **PC**. When bond0(and thus eth2 and eth3) has smaller MTU than Ethernet frames containing ICMP messages on wire, then packet capture utilities like *tcpdump* or *tshark* see only part of the payload part of the ICMP messages. For example lets say that **r1** sends ICMP messages padded with 0xabcd data, then packet capture utilities listening either on bond0, eth2 or eth3 interfaces in **PC** see following data:

```
0x0000:  abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd  ................
0x0010:  abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd  ................
0x0020:  abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd  ................
0x0030:  abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd  ................
0x0040:  abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd abcd  ................
/* further data removed for brevity */
```

What causes such behavior?

Comment: I have no idea, but you should specify at least which device driver is used.

Comment: Also I assume PC has a normal connection too.  (eth0 and eth1?).  Presumably with the same device driver.  Are you saying you've tested pinging PC directly, and it doesn't have the same problem?

Comment: All I know is the tap can't literally be sending you packets like that, because they don't even have the ethernet headers that specify the packet length :).

Comment: Driver in use for both `eth2` and `eth3` is `cdc_ether`(USB CDC Ethernet devices) which depends on `usbnet`, i.e those `eth2` and `eth3` interfaces are USB NICs. If I bond `eth0` and `eth1` interfaces(both use `e1000e` driver), then this behavior does not occur- frames which are larger than interface MTU are simply dropped. So I guess this behavior is specific to USB NICs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `usbnet` seems the most likely culprit.

```
     /* rx and tx sides can use different message sizes;
      * bind() should set rx_urb_size in that case.
      */
     dev->hard_mtu = net->mtu + net->hard_header_len;

     net->netdev_ops = &usbnet_netdev_ops;
     net->watchdog_timeo = TX_TIMEOUT_JIFFIES;
     net->ethtool_ops = &usbnet_ethtool_ops;

     // allow device-specific bind/init procedures
     // NOTE net->name still not usable ...
     if (info->bind) {
             status = info->bind (dev, udev);
             ...
     }
     ....
     if (!dev->rx_urb_size)
             dev->rx_urb_size = dev->hard_mtu;
```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/usb/usbnet.c?v=4.4#L1661

cdc_ether doesn't set `rx_urb_size` itself, as far as I can tell.

I'm assuming the URB size gets passed to the USB controller and the ethernet frames get their heads chopped off to fit (don't ask me why not the other end).  I mean, *hopefully* your experiment isn't causing the hardware to DMA outside of the allocated buffers :).

Even cdc_ether did set rx_urb_size, there's this weird bit in the `ndo_change_mtu` callback in usbnet.  It looks like it could end up being pegged back to mtu, if mtu was ever set to the maximum.

Honestly I don't know how this works, it just looks odd at a first glance.

> ```
>      if (dev->rx_urb_size == old_hard_mtu) {
>              dev->rx_urb_size = dev->hard_mtu;
> ```

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/usb/usbnet.c?v=4.4#L393